# Creating a patch with Git - keep only the basename of the filepath?

Tags: git, patch

My situation is I'm making changes to an installed Drupal module which I want to commit back to the project (yay for open source).  My problem is this:

```
diff --git a/docroot/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/features/features.drush.inc b/docroot/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/features/features.drush.inc
index 0d7a10d..ae5e88b 100644
--- a/docroot/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/features/features.drush.inc
+++ b/docroot/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/features/features.drush.inc
```

Obviously those are the first few lines of the patch file telling the patch command where to find the file to patch.  However, seeing as I want to submit this back to the Features project, I want to chop it off so that `docroot/profiles/commons/modules/contrib/features/` is removed from the path.  So, the above should look like:

```
diff --git a/features.drush.inc b/features.drush.inc
index 0d7a10d..ae5e88b 100644
--- a/features.drush.inc
+++ b/features.drush.inc
```

I've looked over `man git-diff` but I haven't seen anyway to do that (i.e. only keep the filename).  I'm probably blind.

**TL;DR**

How do I keep only the basename of the file path when creating a patch file with Git?

Comment: Why not just edit the patch?

Comment: My line of thought here is that this is such a common thing you see out there in the world of patch files that I just assumed you can flag this on the command line somehow.

Comment: @KevinBallard, OK for a one-shot job; if it will be used with any regularity (or the patches touch many files), better automate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--relative` option of the `git diff` does it.